# How to set application version number in QT for mac OS?

Tags: macos, qt, crash-reports

How can I set the application version number for a QT application so that when it crashes on Mac OS it will get displayed in the crash log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.
You can edit the plist file found in the .app package by adding this key `CFBundleShortVersionString` and adding the version number as a string.